# LaTeX doesn't recognize \columncolor from the colortbl package when when it's in a command

Tags: htlatex, colortbl

LaTeX doesn't recognize the `\columncolor` command from the `colortbl` package when  when it's in a commmand.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand{\cBlue}{\columncolor[rgb]{0,.6,1}}
%\newcommand{\Blue}{\color[rgb]{0,.6,1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\cBlue} cc}
  Blue&White\\
  Blue&White
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\cBlue ->\columncolor 
                      [rgb]{0,.6,1}
l.7   B
       lue&White\\
?
```

Interestingly, htlatex sails through: it gives the expected output of blue colored column.

Note that there is no problem if I replace `\columncolor` by `\color`.

Also, `\rowcolor` is also fine, as you can test it on this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\newcommand{\cBlue}{\columncolor[rgb]{0,.6,1}}
\newcommand{\rBlue}{\rowcolor[rgb]{0,.6,1}}
%\newcommand{\Blue}{\color[rgb]{0,.6,1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \rBlue Blue&Blue\\
  White&White
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to my world:-) That's a feature of the package, yes.

Comment: Can you explain?  Why doesn't  `\rowcolor` or `\color` need this feature?  Why is this feature needed? Isn't it useful to define private mnemonic commands?

Comment: i'll add a few more words to my answer ...

Answer (score 7):

As the error message correctly shows, `\columncolor` is not defined by the `colortbl` package.

It is just used as a placeholder in a modified array preamble parser so that the colour specification can be extracted and re-inserted where needed.

Depending on the actual use case you can parameterise the colour used by defining a columntype or by defining a colour name

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor[rgb]{0,.6,1}}}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0,.6,1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ Bcc>{\columncolor{myblue}}c}
  Blue&White&Blue\\
  Blue&White&Blue
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\color` and `\rowcolor` are defined TeX commands that act at the point they are used. `\columncolor` (because it seemed a good idea at the time sometime in the last millennium) doesn't act at that point (or act at all, there is no command of that name, the internals use it in a similar way to the way `[]` are used to delimit optional arguments, to delimit a colour specification that is extracted and used in the table internals.

Answer (score 5):

Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor[rgb]{0,.6,1}}c}
\begin{document}
\edef\cBlue{}
\begin{tabular}{ B c }
        Blue&White\\
        Blue&White
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  And this also works with htlatex.